# Free Sharepoint 2010 tutorials

Tags: sharepoint

I am a c# web developer and company has gone sharepoint and want me to do a sharepoint website. Any great free sharepoint downloads, articles and/or tutorials out there for a sharepoint beginner? Kindly appreciated. Free lynda tutorial link or torrent is appriciated.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check here

1. [SharePoint Tutorials](http://www.fastsharepoint.com/)
2. [SharePoint videos](http://sharepoint-videos.com/video-categories/all-free-videos/)
3. [sharepoint-tutorial.net](http://sharepoint-tutorial.net/)
4. [sharepoin](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/)
5. [learn-sharepont-2010-basics](http://webtech-training.blogspot.in/2013/11/learn-sharepont-2010-basics.html)

Comment: thank you nagaraj... i have already visited these links 
i want some thing like "beginners"